# Using JavaFX with packages generates "Missing JavaFX application class" error

Tags: java, package, java-8, javafx-8

I'm working on getting started with JavaFX now that it comes with Java 8 and I've run into a strange issue. When running from the default package, my simple Hello World application runs just fine. However, when putting it into a package, trying to run the program gives me the following error:

```
Missing JavaFX application class view/JFXHelloWorld
```

I've included a normal `HelloWorld.java` file in the `view` folder and it works just fine.

To clarify, my file structure looks like this:

`jfx
----src
--------view
------------HelloWorld.java
------------JFXHelloWorld.java
----target
--------view
------------HelloWorld.class
------------JFXHelloWorld.class`

Where target is the folder that I am putting the compiled files into with the following command:

`javac -d target src/view/*.java`

Running the normal HelloWorld.java file works just fine:

`java -cp target view/HelloWorld
Hello, World!`

However, running the JavaFX file causes a problem with the ClassLoader:

`java -cp target view/JFXHelloWorld
Missing JavaFX application class view/JFXHelloWorld`

Googling led me to 9 results, all of which are the source code for the [JavaFX ClassLoader](https://bitbucket.org/shemnon/openjfx-rt/src/f1e4d7e882e3389597973ce31e8b97ff2da988c5/javafx-ui-common/src/com/sun/javafx/application/LauncherImpl.java?at=default).

Both HelloWorld.java and JFXHelloWorld.java are declared to be in `package view;` - is this correct? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

My problem actually was in the command-line call to run HelloWorld.

I should instead be calling the following:

```
java -cp target view.HelloWorld
java -cp target view.JFXHelloWorld
```

For some reason, it allows you to run `view/HelloWorld` when it shouldn't.

Comment: You've uncovered a bug in Java8 and JavaFX integration - running an identical case without javaFX allows the slash '/', instead of the explicit dot '.'

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, your problem it's that JFXHelloWorld it's extending from Application and you aren't setting the classpath correctly. Are you using Java8 or any previous Java release?